# Open directory in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, windows-terminal

Is there any option to open the program files in Windows Terminal directly from the folder's location in the drive, without actually typing all the commands to navigate and then executing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in a number of ways.

1. Click on `File` at the top left corner of the current folder location. You will see `Open Windows PowerShell` option. Click on any option. It will open Power Shell and automatically navigate to the current folder. [image: PowerShell from File Menu]
2. Another option, Press Shift and Right Click. It will show `Open PowerShell window here` option.[image: Open PowerShell windows in context menu]
3. If you are looking for Ubuntu-like terminal(bash) then you can install the Git terminal from [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win). Then, on right-click you will see `Git Bash Here` option.[image: Git Bash Here option in Windows]

Comment: @Lakshman-Palli does this solve your issue? If it does accept the answer, else respond in comment section. So that, I can help you?

Comment: I also found that we can easily open a folder or a file by moving to its location in the drive and entering cmd in its file location at the top :)

Answer (score 0):

I learned a lot from this post! Both the accepted answer and the OP subsequent discovery were very useful to me. May I just add that another useful shortcut to this task is Ctrl+L (to focus in the search bar).

So let's say you are in the File Explorer and want to open the current directory in Terminal, you do:

`Ctrl+L` and then write `terminal` (or`powershell`) and that's it!